# Is it possible to manipulate the value in row for data object from csv in anychart

Tags: anychart

In my understanding when we load data using datafromcsv in anychart  data adapter, it will stored as object and need to map the value in the row.

What is the best way to manipulate  the array if my data in one row contains 3 values and i want to add the 4th value for all the row using a loop.

```
var newDataTable = dataTable.getIterator();
      newDataTable.map(function(row, index, array) {
      var col2 = row.get({value:1});
      var col3 = row.get({value:2});
      var percentage = col2 / col3 * 100;
       row.set('New Column', percentage);
       return row;
        });
```

i tried this line but not really sure with the function (my data is for stock chart)

Comment: We'd like to assist you! 
Please provide us with your JS code and a sample of your data. In this way, we will be able to provide more direct assistance.

Comment: I already solved it. Thanks